# How should I handle None's in context managers in python?

Tags: python, contextmanager

In Python, the following pattern is quite common.

```
thing = x and load_thing(x)
```

which propagates `None` through your code (if `x` is `None` then so is `thing`). This is useful because later in your code you can check if `thing` is None and have different logic.

I'm not sure how to man this play well with context managers: the following code does not work (because if x is None, `with None as y` is not valid (because None does not have `__enter__`)

```
with x and load_thing(x) as y:
    f(y)
```

The best thing I've come up with is this, but I think the people reading my code might curse me (no sense of *fun* I tell you, no sense of fun).

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def const_manager(x):
    yield x


with (const_manager(x) if x is None else load_thing(x)) as y:
    f(y)
```

Is there a more pythonic alternative? Besides layers and layers of function definitions and calls.

Comment: Why not just push the already-loaded check into the context manager?

Comment: Aha, I meant `and` not `or` (in my code I'm using an `if`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the test *in* your wrapper context manager.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def default_manager(cm, x):
    if x is None
        yield x
    else:
        yield cm(x)


with default_manager(load_thing, x) as y:
    f(y)
```

You might also consider using `contextlib.nullcontext` instead.

```
with (load_thing if x is not None else nullcontext)(x) as y:
    f(y)
```

Comment: [nullcontext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) looks like what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the `None` ever reach your context manager.

```
# ...
if x is None:
    return None  # or raise SomeException, depends on context
# ...
with my_context(x) as c:  # Here we do have something to play with
    # ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to fun the body of `with my_context...` with c as `None` rather than erroring out. I've added this context to the question.